# I need to disable Internet In LAN Connection but i need to work with localhost

Tags: internet, connection, lan

I am using zimbra Mail service.i need to block outgoing mails other than local server. so that temporary solution is we need to disable internet in local server while working with lan connection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove your default gateway. Are you using gui or cli? 
Without default gateway settings you can't get to the Internet.